# Mysql wrong date format as text

Tags: mysql

I couldn't find answer of that question..

I have text column like " 18 August 2021 Wednesday" ; it is both wrong type and also wrong format (text);

How can I convert it to standard mysql date format and date type?

Thanks

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET gun = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(gun, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a *new* date column to store the proper date result:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD COLUMN gun_date DATE;
```

Then, populate that date column with the output of `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET gun_date = STR_TO_DATE(gun, '%d %M %Y');
```

If you'd like, you can drop the original `gun` column if you think you won't need it anymore.

Comment: UPDATE Table2 SET gun= STR_TO_DATE(gun, '%d %M %Y');

Than convert text to date format ...Thanx